# Regex to match punctuation and alpha numeric characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to test a string to see if it contains characters other than alphanumeric or punctuation and, if it does, set an error. I have the code below, but it doesn't seem to work as it's letting "CZW205é" pass. I'm hopeless at regex and can't seem to resolve the problem.

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\p{P}]/", $product_id)) {
    $errors[$i] = 'Please only enter alpha-numeric characters, dashes, underscores, colons, full-stops, apostrophes, brackets, commas and forward slashes';
    continue;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do

```
if(preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\p{P}]/", $product_id)) {
    $errors[$i] = 'Please only enter alpha-numeric characters, dashes, underscores, colons, full-stops, apostrophes, brackets, commas and forward slashes';
    continue;
}
```

`[^...]` is a negated character class, it will match as soon as it finds something that is not inside your class.

(And therefor I removed the negation before the `preg_match()`)

Comment: Thanks very much. Sorry for taking so long to reply but I was still getting error 500s so I was testing what else was going wrong before I was completely confident your method was working. And thanks to all other solution providers too!

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\p{P}]+$/
```

Don't forget to mark the end of the string with `$`

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you are only matching the first character, try this code :

```
if(preg_match("/[^\w\s\p{P}]/", $product_id)) {
    $errors[$i] = 'Please only enter alpha-numeric characters, dashes, underscores, colons, full-stops, apostrophes, brackets, commas and forward slashes';
    continue;
}
```

Note : `\w` is a shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: `\w` also includes `\d` and underscore `_`